# Creating an array in JavaScript from JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My JSON file:

```
[{"val0":"Paul","val1":"Jake","val2":null,"val3":"Max"},
 {"val0":"Sam","val1":"Tina","val2":"Emily","val3":"Hardwell"},
 {"val0":"Tom","val1":"Julie","val2":null,"val3":"Adi"}]
```

I want to create an array in javascript as follows:

```
var dataSet=[
  ['Paul','Jake','null','Max'],
  ['Sam','Tina','Emily','Harwell'],
  ['Tom','Julie','null','Adi']
];
```

I tried the following code but it isn’t working. Can anybody please help?

```
$.getJSON("filename.json", function(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push(val);
  });
  // …
});
```

I’m using this array for display purpose (using DataTables), so, I want to create the array in that format.I'm using the dataSet array for displaying in DataTables as follows:

```
var dataSet = [
    ['Paul','Jake','Isha','Mike','null','null','Parth','Tinker'],
    ['Tina','Michael','null','Blue','Red','','Emily','Mina']
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' );
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Name" },
            { "title": "Deadline" },
            { "title": "Additional fees" },
            { "title": "Requirements" },
            { "title": "Field" },
            { "title": "Award" },
            { "title": "Renewable requirements"},
            { "title": "Link" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Is the file running from a server?

Comment: Try a `/` in front of `filename.json`.

Comment: Please specify what error message or output do you receive.

Comment: What do you do with `items`? Do you ever return it anywhere? Or do you just throw it away?

Comment: The html file is not displaying anything, I'm not getting any error messages. Also I'm passing that array to other function.

Comment: The code I have posted for displaying content in DataTables is working. Problem is I have around 500 records in the JSON file, I want to build the dataSet array in similar fashion from JSON file and my code will work. The code you have suggested is giving me the desired array but I don't know why it isn't displaying anything. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You get an array of objects, and you want an array of arrays, so convert each object to an array by reading the properties of the object:

```
var items = [];
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
  items.push([val.val0,val.val1,val.val2,val.val3]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
  $(function() {

    $.getJSON("filename.json", function(data) {
      var items = [];
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {

          var tmp = [];
          for (var Key in val) {
            tmp.push(val[Key]);
          }

        items.push(tmp);
      });
      console.log(items);
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without jquery:

```js
var data = [
        { "val0": "Paul", "val1": "Jake", "val2": null, "val3": "Max" },
        { "val0": "Sam", "val1": "Tina", "val2": "Emily", "val3": "Hardwell" },
        { "val0": "Tom", "val1": "Julie", "val2": null, "val3": "Adi" }
    ],
    dataSet = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var i, a0 = [];
        for (i in a) {
            a0.push(a[i]);
        }
        r.push(a0);
        return r;
    }, []);
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dataSet, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: I  tried the above code but it isn't displaying anything in DataTables. Can you please suggest something?

Comment: I want to display content from JSON file, the code I have used for DataTables, works if I provide the dataSet array in the above format but I want to create that array from JSON file in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

#### One liner:

```
var dataSet = rawData.map(function(e){ return Object.keys(e).map(function(i){ return e[i]}); })
```

#### Output:

[image: Creating an array in JavaScript from JSON file]

#### Output as JSON:

[image]

#### Method explanation (from Javascript Reference)

1. The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
2. The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties

Comment: @Swap, do this match the desired output?